# AVPlayer not working on iPhone 5s 64bit iOS 7.0.3

Tags: ios, iphone, avplayer

I'm trying to figure out an issue that only appears on the iPhone5s having to do with an AVPlayer playing a video. The issue is that a movie will play on all devices I have tested so far except for the 5s 64bit model.

My theory is that it is tied to being 64bit but I haven't been able to tie it to anything. I found another stackoverflow post relating a similar issue with the fix being tied to using autolayout. However, I am not using autolayout.

This code has been working great until the 5s:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.somemovieurlhere.mp4"]];
    AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
    playerLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:playerLayer];

    [self.player play];
}
```

I know the layer is added, because if you set the background color it shows up in the view, but no movie ever plays. In my project I can tell the movie is playing by logging out the "currentTime" property like so:

```
float time = CMTimeGetSeconds([player currentTime]);
```

Here is an image of the movie from an iphone4s and what I see in an iphone5s. I have also tested this with an original iphone5 and it works fine.

[image: iphone4s] [image: iphone5s]

Any ideas as to what might be causing this? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Apple's latest update 7.0.4 fixed this issue. Their update just came out today.

Thanks!